# Rails - Kaminari - paginate_array returns duplicate records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I'm trying to paginate the following array. At the moment the table is being appended to, but only with the same records as the first page:

```
def collection
  @collection ||= begin
    viewable_pupils.where(level: level, group_id: group_id).ordered
      .map{ |p| Schools::Admin::PupilReportTableFacade.new(p, school.calendar_range_for_year_starting(report_start_year)) }
  end
  @collection = Kaminari.paginate_array(@collection).page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
helper_method :collection
```

My view is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <%= render 'schools/admin/reporting/collection_partial' %>
</div>
<%= link_to 'Load More', school_reporting_load_more_path, remote: true, id: "load_more_link", class: 'btn btn-info' %>
```

And the partial being rendered:

```
<% collection.each do |pupil| %>
  <div class="well well--bordered well--skinny well--collapse-pad well--shadow">
    <div class="marking-header marking-header--table marking-header--table-even">
      <div class="marking-header__cell">
        <%= pupil.first_name %>
      </div>
      <div class="marking-header__cell"><%= pupil.last_name %></div>
      <div class="marking-header__cell" align="center">
        <% pupil.histories.each do |history| %>
          <% next unless school.calendar_range_for_year_starting(report_start_year).cover?(history[:created_at]) %>
          <%= history[:year] %>   <%= history[:level] %>
          <%= history[:created_at] %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="marking-header__cell">
        <%= "Total completed: #{pupil.pupil.activities_completed_year_starting(report_start_year)}" %></br>
        <%= "(#{pupil.pupil.comprehensions_completed_year_starting(report_start_year)} x comprehensions)" unless pupil.pupil.comprehensions_completed_year_starting(report_start_year).zero? %></br>
        <%= "(#{pupil.pupil.crosswords_completed_year_starting(report_start_year)} x crosswords)" unless pupil.pupil.crosswords_completed_year_starting(report_start_year).zero? %></br>
        <%= "(#{pupil.pupil.debates_completed_year_starting(report_start_year)} x debates" unless pupil.pupil.debates_completed_year_starting(report_start_year).zero? %></br>
        <%= "(#{pupil.pupil.word_definitions_completed_year_starting(report_start_year)} x word definitions" unless pupil.pupil.word_definitions_completed_year_starting(report_start_year).zero? %>
        <div class="gems">
          <% pupil.milestone_badges.each do |badge| %>
            <%= image_tag image_path(badge.image), class: 'gem' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="marking-header__cell">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pupils[]" value="<%= pupil.id %>" class="tick-check" id="check-<%= pupil.id %>" data-behaviour="update-compare-count">
        <label for="check-<%= pupil.id %>"></label>
        <%= "Total this year: #{pupil.pupil.total_points_this_year}" %></br>
        <%= "(Total all time: #{pupil.pupil.total_points})" %></br></br>
        <%= "iHub points: #{pupil.pupil.score}" %></br>
        <%= "Teacher Points: #{pupil.pupil.total_points_year_starting(report_start_year)}" %></br>
        <%= "Words Read: #{pupil.pupil.words_read_year_starting(report_start_year)}" %></br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Finally my ajax:

```
$('.container').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'schools/admin/reporting/collection_partial')%>");
$('#load_more_link').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(link_to 'Load More', school_reporting_load_more_path, remote: true, id: "load_more_link", class: 'btn btn-info')%>");
```

If any more info is needed please ask, I feel I've tried everything I can think of at this point.

Comment: does `@collection` contain duplicates also? (before using the Kaminari paginate method)

Comment: No - I wasn't supplying params to the link_to - changing that fixed it - thanks for your time